# (iPhone)How to change font size of a row in tableview

Tags: iphone, fonts, tableview

Hi I am now working on changing font size of a row. There seem to be no such settings in inspector. And I dont know which delegate method to override. Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
//Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]; //Change this value to adjust size
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2; //Change this value to show more or less lines.
cell.textLabel.text = @"This is my text";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//font size
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answers your question, but inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate you can set cell.textLabelfont to a [UIFont](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html).